# Unexpected behavior from Apply

Tags: syntax, core-language

Right up front: I'm an absolute novice with Mathematica, never had to use it until very recently, and I'm entirely self-taught (with a little help from friends with some level of experience). I'm very confused by why the following gives me the result it does:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

functionName = "addOneToAll";

addOne[num_] := Block[{newNum},
   newNum = num + 1;
   Return[newNum];
   ];

addOneToAll[matrix_] := Map[addOne, matrix, {2}];

doOperation[fn_, target_] := Apply[fn, {target}];

Print[doOperation[functionName, a]];
```

This gives me the output `addOneToAll[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]` which, if evaluated, should be `{{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}`. And, if I replace the last line by `Print[addOneToAll[a]]`, sure enough, that's what I get. I'm very confused, and I know it's just a matter of inexperience.

Comment: I think you are looking for `ToExpression` instead of `Apply`. `Apply` does not transform a string to a command.

Comment: @Felix Agh! Thank you! I _thought_ that seemed too straightforward to work, but the way it was explained to me implied that it did. Changed `Apply[fn, {target}];` to `Apply[ToExpression[fn], {target}];` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a string for `functionName` but rather a symbol.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

functionName = addOneToAll;

addOne[num_] := Block[{newNum}, newNum = num + 1;
  Return[newNum];]

addOneToAll[matrix_] := Map[addOne, matrix, {2}]

doOperation[fn_, target_] := Apply[fn, {target}]
```

You don't need to use `Print` when invoking `doOperation`.

```
doOperation[functionName, a]
(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}} *)
```

If you want to use a string for the function name try:

```
doString[fn_String, target_] := Apply[ToExpression[fn], {target}]
```

and then

```
doString["addOneToAll", a]
(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}} *)
```

or without `Apply`

```
doString[fn_String, target_] := ToExpression[fn][target]

doString["addOneToAll", a]
(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}} *)
```

Tip: No harm is done by placing a semi-colon on the same line as defining the functions but it is not needed (there is no output).